# Not getting a way to apply regEx to time input

Tags: jquery, regex, datetime, timepicker

*I am working on timepicker and want to restrict user to enter time more than `23:59`. i am trying this using regEx but not getting succeed*

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KsvdK/33/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="test1" placeholder="HH:MM"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#test1").keypress(function(e) {
    var regex = ["([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])",":","[0-5][0-9]"],
    string = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which),b = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (!new RegExp("^" + regex[i] + "$").test(string[i])) {
            b = false;
        }    
    }
    return b;
});
```

It's not giving any error but can't figure out what is happening.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You could test every character against its own regular expression;

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KsvdK/43/)

Try

```
$("#test1").keypress(function(event) 
{
   var regexs = [/[0-2]/,/[0-3]/,/:/,/[0-5]/,/[0-9]/];

   var key = event.which;

   var string = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(key)

   var characters  = string.split("");

   var passed = true;

   var isBackspace = key === 8;

   var shouldTest = characters.length < 5 && ! isBackspace;

   passed = ! ( characters.length > 5 && ! isBackspace );

   if(shouldTest)
   {
       for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) 
       {
           var character = characters[i];
           var regex = regexs[i];

           var testFailed = ! regex.test(character) ;

           if( testFailed ) 
           { 
               passed = false; 
               break;
           }

       }
   }

   return passed; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This expression will:

- match only valid time from `00:00` to `23:59`
- capture the hours and minute elements of the string

`^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$`

[image]

Live example here: http://www.rubular.com/r/moV2nTFpF4

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Evaqk/

Comment: Thank you for the response, But i am familiar with the expressions, i just not getting it worked in my code with `keypress()` as you can see it in fiddle. Thank you once again for Nice example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Evaqk/  I'm not sure keypress is the best solution, as it'll attempt to validate the string for every keypress, you might consider the blur event.